# How to get highest salary from male and female in sql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a small question, how can I get `highest salary` from `male` and `female`  column.

```
------+----------------+----------------+
Id.         Gender.           Salary
-----+-----------------+----------------+
1.           F.               3000
2.           M.               4000
3.           F.               3500
4.           M                3999
```

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) AS max_salary
FROM emp
GROUP BY Salary
HAVING
```

I don't know furthur how to achieve.

I have posted this from my mobile phone so please help me by editing the question.

Please help as my MySQL knowledge is limited.

Comment: Show your table structure or you can use employee type in having clause but i will prefer to user where clause before group by clause.

Comment: Do you want to get different results? As in, highest salary for male column, and highest from female column OR highest salary for both columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`MAX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html), and then [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html/) on the `Gender` field to achieve this:

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) AS max_salary,
       Gender
FROM emp
GROUP BY Gender
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b493c/1)

Answer (score 0):

Execute:

```
mysql> select gender,max(salary) from [tablename] group by gender;
```

As per your usecase, the original table:

[image]

And the resultset:

[image]

Some hands-on on [**group by**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html/) [MySQL Official Documentation]

Comment: Please. No images.

Comment: For clarity, @Strawberry means please include code as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of images.

Comment: Got it. But I still cannot comprehend including images warranted a downvote.

Comment: Your answer is not accessible to people using screen readers.

Comment: The first thing I provided was the code snippet which can be easily copied or translated. It's easier to visualise things at times to comprehend. If I would just have pasted pictures, then the content in the link shared by @Will would have been justified. Sharing the code and showing what it does, isn't that bad an idea.